# Accessing $language inside node content in drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes, i18n-l10n

Normally I would use $language to get the active language on my drupal 7 page. Now I'm doing some changes to a node content (set to PHP code) and I can't seem to get any variables working? I badly need to get the active language inside the node content - how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your question:

```
global $language_content;
```

This will return a language object with the current language.

Comment: It works! Thank you. I wonder why it was so hard to find this variable.

Comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/globals/7

Comment: @corbacho: I already had looked at the docs but misunderstood the difference between $language and $language_content. It seems clear to me now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It also works within a block. I created a PHP block where I wanted to customize a link with the language variable, and placed this code inside:

```
<?php global $language_content; print $language_content->language; ?>
```

Thank you for sharing!